# Roll up image implementation using canvas - Python

Tags: python, image, canvas, tkinter

I want an image to scroll up inside a canvas. But I am unable to do it.

```
import tkinter


def scroll_image(event):
    global roll
    roll = roll - 10
    canvas1.itemconfig(canvas1.create_image(20, roll, image=i))


roll = 10
windows = tkinter.Tk()
windows.title("My Application")


# Adding canvas to show image there
canvas1 = tkinter.Canvas(windows, width=200, height=100)
i = tkinter.PhotoImage(file="Capture.gif")
canvas1.create_image(20, 20, image=i)

# trying to implement roll-up image
canvas1.itemconfig(canvas1.create_image(20, 20, image=i))
canvas1.bind("<Configure>", scroll_image)

canvas1.grid(column=0, row=2)


windows.mainloop()
```

I tried using loops but I noticed that loops are running as expected but unfortunately the canvas update is taking place only once. So I removed the loop. But I need to find a way out to implement a roll up image.

Comment: How did you create loop? Did you use `window.after()` to create function which doesn't stops `mainloop()` which redraws elements in window? Or do you use `window.update()` in loop to ask `mainloop() to redraw window ?

Comment: @furas nope I just used a for loop. You see I am a beginner, trying hard to learn Python on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Image is moving up and down.

This example use

- module `PIL/pillow` to load `jpg/png` instead of `gif`
- `after(time_in_millisecond, function_name)` to repeat function which moves image
- `img_id` to use only one image (instead of creating many images with `create_image`)
- `canvas.move(ID, offset_x, offset_y)` to move image (or other object)
- `canvas.coords(ID)` to get current positon of image (or other object)
- `canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True)` to use full window. Canvas will use full window even when you resize window.

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


def scroll_image():
    global offset_y  # inform function that you want to assign value to external variable instead of local one.

    # move image
    canvas.move(img_id, offset_x, offset_y)

    # get current position
    x, y = canvas.coords(img_id)
    print(x, y)

    # set position (if you don't use canvas.move)
    #canvas.coords(img_id, x+offset_x, y+offset_y)
    # x += offset_x
    # y += offset_y

    # change direction
    if y <= -100 or y >= 0:
        offset_y = -offset_y

    # repeat after 20ms
    root.after(20, scroll_image)


offset_x = 0
offset_y = -3

root = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(root)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True) # use full window

#photo = tk.PhotoImage(file="Capture.gif")
image = Image.open("image.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
img_id = canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=photo)

# start scrolling
scroll_image()

root.mainloop()
```

You can use also `canvas.coords(ID, x, y)` to set new position.

---

More examples on GitHub for: [Tkinter](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/tree/master/tkinter) and [other Python's modules](https://github.com/furas/python-examples)

Comment: I haven't run it yet, but is there any option to achieve the same result without using PIL module? Because that module is not built-in, actually for this I want to use only the built-in modules.

Comment: without PIL you can use only GIF or PPM. Doc: [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: without that restriction, do I have any issue? Because if that is the only restriction, I can manage with it.

Comment: all depend what you need. tkinter has some other problems. You can draw on canvas but it can't save it in bitmap file - you can save only in postscript. It can't display HTML. Widgets can't have transparent background - so you can't create transparent window or window with irregular shape. It can't get key events when its window has no focus - you can't create keylogger or globals keys which can run function when window is minimalized.

Comment: but at start you have to know about bug in PhotoImage - it removes image when it is created in function (or class) and assigned to local variable. More at the bottom of page [PhotoImage](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm)

Comment: Ok. What is the best alternative to tkinter module? And I want to learn about variables, classes etc that starts with _ and some start and end with _ too. What they are called? Can you please provide the link for learning it?

Comment: good for all systems (Windows/Linux/Mac) can be `PyQt5` and `PySide2`. Both use library `Qt` (ver 5.x). For Linux good is `PyGtk` - it can be preinstalled because many programs on Linux use `Gtk` and `PyGtk`. Third can be `wxPython` which uses library `wxWidgets`. Items with _ are called "magic". I don't have links to tutorials. I always use Google to find answer. And I prefer links to answers on Stackoverflow. At this moment I remeber only [Zeef](https://python.zeef.com/alan.richmond), [Awesome Python](https://github.com/vinta/awesome-python), [ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/)

Comment: thank you so much. Good info. In the meantime I read a bit on magic function.

Comment: I have checked PyQt5. But unfortunately there is not much description on the official page.

Comment: Check tutorials in ZetCode on on [TutorialsPoints](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/). In [official wiki on python.org](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt/Tutorials) you can also find tutorials. If you don't need tutorials but only list of functions in classes then probably it can be easier to check documentation for Qt (C/C++). PyQt5 ans PySide2 mostly use the same names as Qt, with the same arguments,etc.